# SqlAlchemy Query.All() Unexpectedly Returning OperationalError

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy, jinja2, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm implementing search functionality using Elasticsearch in a "Reddit clone" web application that I'm developing. I want to support searching for threads, users, and subreddits, but when I enter a search query and search for one of the 3 above mentioned categories that does not hold any matches, I'm getting an unexpected "OperationalError" instead of an empty set of results.

As shown in the code I included, I attempted to use the sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.all() function which returned the following error:

```
OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) near "END": syntax error
[SQL: SELECT user.id AS user_id, user.username AS user_username, user.email AS user_email, user.password_hash AS user_password_hash, user.last_sign_in AS user_last_sign_in 
FROM user 
WHERE 1 != 1 ORDER BY CASE user.id END]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)
```

I researched other StackOverflow posts and found that the first() function internally processes the database result and returns None if no results are found, but when I switched to that function, I faced this error:

```
OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) near "END": syntax error
[SQL: SELECT user.id AS user_id, user.username AS user_username, user.email AS user_email, user.password_hash AS user_password_hash, user.last_sign_in AS user_last_sign_in 
FROM user 
WHERE 1 != 1 ORDER BY CASE user.id END
 LIMIT ? OFFSET ?]
[parameters: (1, 0)]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)
```

Checking the documentation for SqlAlchemy, I don't see any mention of this error in either function, and reading the meaning of OperationalError, I'm concerned that my database setup is possibly incorrect.

app/routes.py: This is the route that handles search requests made to the following URL: http://localhost:5000/search?q=&index=

```
@app.route('/search', methods=['GET'])
def search():
    print 'Hit the /search route!'
    if not g.search_form.validate():
        return redirect(url_for('index'))
    page = request.args.get('page', 1, type=int)
    target_index = request.args.get('index', 'thread')
    if target_index == 'thread':
        results, total = Thread.search(g.search_form.q.data, page, app.config['POSTS_PER_PAGE'])
        print 'Called Thread.search(), total results = {}'.format(total['value'])
    elif target_index == 'user':
        results, total = User.search(g.search_form.q.data, page, app.config['POSTS_PER_PAGE'])
        print 'Called User.search(), total results = {}'.format(total['value'])
    elif target_index == 'subreddit':
        results, total = Subreddit.search(g.search_form.q.data, page, app.config['POSTS_PER_PAGE'])
        print 'Called Subreddit.search(), total results = {}'.format(total['value'])
    else:
        return render_template('404.html')
    try:
        results = results.all()
    except OperationalError:
        results = [None]
    total = total['value']
    next_url = url_for('search', index=target_index, q=g.search_form.q.data, page=page + 1) if total > page * app.config['POSTS_PER_PAGE'] else None
    prev_url = url_for('search', index=target_index, q=g.search_form.q.data, page=page - 1) if page > 1 else None
    results_list = zip(results, [None] * len(results)) # Temporarily to match expected input for template
    return render_template('search.html', title=_('Search'), results_list=results_list, next_url=next_url, prev_url=prev_url, query=g.search_form.q.data, index=target_index)
```

app/models.py:

```
class SearchableMixin(object):
    @classmethod
    def search(cls, expression, page, per_page):
        ids, total = query_index(cls.__tablename__, expression, page, per_page)
        if total == 0:
            return cls.query.filter_by(id=0), 0
        when = []
        for i in range(len(ids)):
            when.append((ids[i], i))
        return cls.query.filter(cls.id.in_(ids)).order_by(
            db.case(when, value=cls.id)), total

    @classmethod
    def before_commit(cls, session):
        session._changes = {
            'add': list(session.new),
            'update': list(session.dirty),
            'delete': list(session.deleted)
        }

    @classmethod
    def after_commit(cls, session):
        for obj in session._changes['add']:
            if isinstance(obj, SearchableMixin):
                add_to_index(obj.__tablename__, obj)
        for obj in session._changes['update']:
            if isinstance(obj, SearchableMixin):
                add_to_index(obj.__tablename__, obj)
        for obj in session._changes['delete']:
            if isinstance(obj, SearchableMixin):
                remove_from_index(obj.__tablename__, obj)
        session._changes = None

    @classmethod
    def reindex(cls):
        for obj in cls.query:
            add_to_index(cls.__tablename__, obj)

db.event.listen(db.session, 'before_commit', SearchableMixin.before_commit)
db.event.listen(db.session, 'after_commit', SearchableMixin.after_commit)

# Below is one model that implements SearchableMixin to allow searching # for users. Thread and Subreddit models follow the same logic.
class User(db.Model, UserMixin, SearchableMixin):
    __searchable__ = ['username']
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(64), index=True, unique=True)
    # <Remaining User model fields here...>
```

app/search.py: (Holds the underlying search functions to query Elasticsearch indices)

```
def add_to_index(index, model):
    if not app.elasticsearch:
        return
    payload = {}
    for field in model.__searchable__:
        payload[field] = getattr(model, field)
    app.elasticsearch.index(index=index, doc_type=index, id=model.id,
                                    body=payload)

def remove_from_index(index, model):
    if not app.elasticsearch:
        return
    app.elasticsearch.delete(index=index, doc_type=index, id=model.id)

def query_index(index, query, page, per_page):
    if not app.elasticsearch:
        return [], 0
    search = app.elasticsearch.search(
        index=index,
        body={'query': {'multi_match': {'query': query, 'fields': ['*']}},
              'from': (page - 1) * per_page, 'size': per_page})
    ids = [int(hit['_id']) for hit in search['hits']['hits']]
    return ids, search['hits']['total']
```

As my included app/routes.py shows, I made a workaround by catching the OperationalError and treating it as an indicator that no results were found, but since the all() documentation makes no mention of it, I did not expect there to be this exception being raised.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simplified the generated query a bit by hiding all fields you retrieve behind the asterisk.

```
SELECT user.*
FROM user 
WHERE 1 != 1
ORDER BY CASE user.id END
```

First of all, this query will not return any values as long as `1 != 1` is a where clause, since that is false by definition. Is it possible `ids` is empty? That might also very much explain the ill-formatted `CASE` statement, which is the source of the error. Normally, `case(dict(a=1, b=2), value=User.name)` should result in `CASE WHEN name = 'a' THEN 1 WHEN name = 'b' THEN 2 END`, which would properly execute.

Comment: I checked my User model's table and saw that all users have unique, incrementing ```id``` fields (starting with 1). I looked into what the CASE statement does, and it seems that the "normally" description you gave above is the "conventional" way to use it. In my case, would it not simply return the user.id field and order it in ascending order (the default ordering)?

Comment: Not really, because `whens` in your code is a mapping of id's to an ordering, note that `i` comes from `range(len(ids))`, so I think the idea is that it's supposed to replicate the ordering from ElasticSearch. If you simply want to order by id, lose the `case` and just use `.order_by(cls.id)`

Comment: I figured out that the issue was due to an improper check for an empty set of matches from Elasticsearch, in my ```SearchableMixin```'s ```search()``` function. The ```total``` output in that function, which comes from my app/search.py module's ```query_index()``` function, was actually a dictionary holding {'relation': 'eq', 'value', 0}, so I updated that function to grab the 'value' key's value. Upvoting and accepting this answer because it led me to double check the relevant work I did, and gave me more insight into SqlAlchemy's CASE implementation.